# Append a character in a string of a certain field

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I am familiar with the basics of sed awk and grep. I have a file with 11 fields. In the 10th and 11th field I have latitude and longitude coordinates. They are structured like this: -5555555. What I would like to do is insert a period after two digits in both fields. So desired result would be -55.5555 . Using awk/sed or any other tool, what would my best way of going about this be?

Sample of file:

```
01 00460 Adamsville city     AL    4161   1554 0000007948 0000000000 +33595542 -086957993
```

Comment: i see more then 6 fields here

Comment: I updated that question, I intend to change the last two fields.

Comment: then my approach doesn't work here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using awk you can do:

```
awk '{for (i=NF-1; i<=NF; i++) sub(/^[-+]?[0-9][0-9]/, "&.", $i)} 1' file
01 00460 Adamsville city AL 4161 1554 0000007948 0000000000 +33.595542 -08.6957993
```

This awk command searches for regex pattern `[-+]?[0-9][0-9]` at the start of in last 2 fields  and replaces it with *matched text + dot*.

#### [Code Demo](http://ideone.com/DDWA9D)

Comment: What does the "1" do at the end of the awk command? @anubhava

Comment: `1` means default action which is to print the output.

Comment: Hmm, I tried this on my file, however it did not change the fields

Comment: I added a sample of the file

Comment: Yes I actually meant 10th and 11th field.

Comment: It seems as though nothing is changing on the output @anubhava

Comment: I have also added a working demo in my answer. I suggest faster responses from your side.

Comment: Thank you!! With a little playing around, your answer worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

Through sed,

```
sed 's/^\( *\([^ ]\+ \+\)\{4\}-*[0-9]\{2\}\)\([^ ]* \+-*[0-9]\{2\}\)/\1.\3./' file
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat file
foo v v v -5555555 55555
$ sed 's/^\( *\([^ ]\+ \+\)\{4\}-*[0-9]\{2\}\)\([^ ]* \+-*[0-9]\{2\}\)/\1.\3./' file
foo v v v -55.55555 55.555
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution in awk without using regex

```
echo " 1 2 3 4 -5555555"|awk '{print substr($5, "1","3") "." substr($5,"4") }'
-55.55555
```

Explanation: prints first 3 chars (including `-`sign), a period and then remaining chars.

Answer (score 0):

With plain old bash, using **substring pattern matching** is about the simplest way:

```
 a="5555555 55555"; b=-${a/555/55.}; b=${b/\ 55555/ 55.55.};  echo "b: $b"
  -55.5555 55.55
```

I am somewhat confused as to the exact result desired. If it needs tweaking let me know.